# How do I write contents of an array to elements in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm taking part in week 4 of [How to Learn JavaScript Properly](http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/) and i'm working on the dynamic quiz. Here is my progress:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var allQuestions = [
    {
        question: "Who is Prime Minister of the UK?",
        choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
        correctAnswer: 0
    },
    {
        question: "For how long is a dog pregnant?",
        choices: ["9 Weeks", "9 Days", "9 Months", "9 Fortnights"],
        correctAnswer: 0
    }
];

var qQty = allQuestions.length
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*qQty);
var currentQ = allQuestions[randomNum];

$("h1").text(currentQ.question)

for (var i = 0; i < currentQ.choices.length; i++) {
    $("label:eq(i)").text("currentQ.choices[i]")
};
});
```

Also here's the gist of my HTML:

```
<form>
    <h1>Q. - ?</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><label for="choice-1">label</label> <input type="radio" name="quiz" id="choice-1" value=""></li>
        <li><label for="choice-2">label</label> <input type="radio" name="quiz" id="choice-2" value=""></li>
        <li><label for="choice-3">label</label> <input type="radio" name="quiz" id="choice-3" value=""></li>
        <li><label for="choice-4">label</label> <input type="radio" name="quiz" id="choice-4" value=""></li>
    </ul>
    <button id="next-btn">Next</button>
</form>
```

Number of questions has been trimmed for clarity. I'm currently using jQuery to try to write the multiple choice answers to 4 label elements in the DOM.

It's currently broken. I'm wanting to use the `i` variable inside the `$("label:eq(i)")` but it's not happening.

First thing I'd like to fix is the four labels. Would love to know if I'm on a good track. I realise that there's probably a cleaner way so please suggest alternatives.

Thanks, Alistair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < currentQ.choices.length; i++) {
    $("label:eq(" + i + ")").text(currentQ.choices[i]);
};
```

Right now, you're trying to use i as an iterator, but not inserting the value of i, but the literal string "i". Same with the part of currentQ.choices[i] ... you were making that a whole string, instead of inserting the value from that array item.

Comment: Yes. fixed.

    $("label:eq(" + i + ")").text( currentQ.choices[i])

Thanks mori :)

Comment: I'll have more questions soon, should I post in here or post another question?

Comment: I think the general feeling is that if it's not directly related to the issue you had in the first question, you should open another question.